# How to use Async Await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a Main Method inside my WCF service. Please help me to point where exactly i need to put Aync and Await. I have 2 methods inside main method , one method updates a table and another method fetches values from SQl and i return back the values as object to client.I want 2 methods to execute in Parallel. I want to quickly return the object to the client

```
public object GetSensorConfiguration(string desc)
{
   object oObject = null;
   UpdateTable(desc);
   oObject = GetobjectValue(desc);
   return oObject ;
}

private void updatetable(string desc)
{
    // no return value.. just update    
}

private object GetobjectValue(string desc)
{
    object objA = null;
    //Get values for the objA;
    return objA;
}
```

Comment: Is the GetobjectValue method dependant on updatetable method being run first ?

Comment: No. Update and get are both seperate process and are independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you start with your database calls, e.g., using the asynchronous APIs that are available in Entity Framework:

```
private async Task UpdateTableAsync(string desc)
{
  ...
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}

private async Task<object> GetObjectValue(string desc)
{
  object objA = await ...;
  return objA;
}
```

Then you can consume them in your "main" method. Since you want to execute them concurrently (not "parallel"), then you'd want to use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public async Task<object> GetSensorConfiguration(string desc)
{
  var updateTask = UpdateTableAsync(desc);
  var getTask = GetObjectValueAsync(desc);
  await Task.WhenAll(updateTask, getTask);
  return await getTask;
}
```

Comment: Curious whether, once you know a task is completed, there is any advantage to await getTask over getTask.Result?

Comment: Ah answering for myself, I guess it throws any pending exception?

Comment: @sellotape: They both throw exceptions, but `await` will throw the exception you're expecting. `Result` wraps any exception in an `AggregateException`. Also, `await` is more resilient to code changes (e.g., if the method is refactored and now the task may or may not be complete).